# Cartthrob Realex Redirect (Global Iris) - 505 error - URL masked

Tags: cartthrob

Everything works fine in Chrome.

However in Internet Explorer and Firefox, submitting the check out form results in an error message from Realex/Global Iris:

505 You cannot use this service from there.

Global Iris say that their logs suggest that the submission URL is somehow being masked - hence it doesn't match the referral URL that they have on record, so the request fails.

edit: if I type document.referrer into the browser console, Chrome shows http://www.domain.com/cart/checkout, while both IE and FF show nothing.

Comment: We are going to need more information like what version of EE and CT are you using? Have you looked at the developer console in Firefox or IE to see that the submission URL is? Do you have any redirects in your htaccess that might be causing this?

Comment: @JustinLong Thank you for your reply. It's EE v2.7.3 and CT v2.5. The developer consoles in FF, IE, and Chrome all appear to show the same things for the form's hidden fields - the RET field is http://www.domain.com/cart/checkout, and the URI field is just cart/checkout - not sure if the latter field should be the full URL or not. My htaccess file is just the EE-recommended one for removing index.php. I should mention that the domain is a Domain Add On in CPanel - the host thinks this is fine - but I do wonder if it might be the cause. Thanks again.

Comment: Stumbled across this from Google debugging a 505 error. It appears this error code is also used when a referring URL and/or IP is not whitelisted to use the Global Iris payment page.

Answer (score 0):

Admin ‣ System Administration ‣ Output and Debugging ‣ Redirection Method ‣ Location (faster).

Not sure why it defaults to the Windows option.